# Is there a way to add richfaces dropSupport to the header of a tab element?

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

I've got a problem using Richfaces-3.3.3 with JBoss-Seam 2.2 as my environment:

I have a richfaces `<rich:dataTable>` inside a `<rich:tab>`. The parent tabPanel has two tabs total, so the structure is like this:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" selectedTab="t1">
  <rich:tab id="t1" label="List1">...</rich:tab>
  <rich:tab id="t2" label="List2">
    <rich:dataTable value="#{objList}" var="obj">
      <rich:column><a4j:outputPanel>
        <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator" dragType="talent" dragValue="${obj}"/>
           <h:outputText value="#{obj.score}"/>
         </rich:dragSupport>
       </a4j:outputPanel></rich:column>
     </rich:dataTable>
  </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

Now I want to drag `#{obj.score}` to `t1`'s header and drop it there, calling a backing method that would add `obj` to the list contained in `t1`.

I can't add `<rich:dropSupport>` inside t1, `tab` does not support a header facet, and wrapping `rich:tab` in a `rich:dropSupport` tag makes the tab disappear.

So - is there a way to have the header of a `rich:tab` generate drop events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution in months and no answers here says "no, there is no way" is the answer.